# Phonegap desktop error on create new project

Tags: cordova, phonegap-desktop-app

I installed Phonegap Desktop on my Win 7 laptop.

Now I open it and click on "New project".
After selecting "Hello world" template I choose a directory on my local drive and fill in a name.

When I click on Create button, after some seconds, it show an error message "Project Create failed with code 1".

Any idea?

With thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 1):

run phonegap as an administrator and it will work

Answer (score 0):

first install [node.js](http://nodejs.org/)

next install [Git](https://git-scm.com/)

next install phonegap

note: ***all 32 or 64 bit os*** and  **run phonegap as administrator**

Answer (score 0):

today I started up again investigating on my old phonegap project so I updated the Phonegap Desktop application with the new version present on-line.... and magically it started working fine.